# How to log some data on console?

Tags: python, angularjs, logging, flask, console

I'm making website using AngularJS and Flask.

AngularJS controller, `some_controller.js` posts JSON data to `/url`.

And in flask, I want to get data and use it like below.

```
@route('/url')
def somefunction():
    filter = json.loads(request.data)
    namefilter = filter.get('name', '')
```

But it doesn't work so I want to log whether filter gets correct data or not.
How can I log `filter` in console?

Comment: If you mean printing log on Python's console, then simply you can use `Logger.debug(filter)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular should send the data back with the correct `content-type`  header, so you should be able to just use

```
payload = request.json
print payload
#if using py3 print(payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do so from the Angular side, then you can use

```
console.log('filter log' + filter);
```

or the custom `$log` provider.